# Remove google maps custom marker on mouseout

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The map I have created has multiple areas outlined with polygons. When the user mouses over a section a custom marker pops up, and on mouse out the marker disappears. I have got everything working, but cannot figure out how to get the marker to disappear on mouseout. The code below is not every section, but I am hoping just showing how one section works will provide enough information. I'm a bit new to the Maps API and javascript, so I'm hoping I set the first part up right, but I would love any suggestions. I'm thinking I need to somehow have access to the marker in the noMarker function...

```
    //Sets up the polygon    
    var mapWC = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordsWC,
        strokeColor: "#14b400",
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: "#14b400",
        sectionName: "West Cambridge",
        markerImage: 'images/hood-marker.png',
        markerLL: new google.maps.LatLng(42.3751819960975,-71.15445431301595),
        fillOpacity: 0.33
        });

     mapWC.setMap(map);

//Mouse in and out
     google.maps.event.addListener(mapWC, 'mouseover', showMarker);
     google.maps.event.addListener(mapWC, 'mouseout', noMarker);

//functions
function showMarker(){
//var secName = this.sectionName;
//console.log(secName);
var image = this.markerImage;
var myLatLng = this.markerLL;
var themarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
icon: image
});
} // End showMarker

function noMarker(){
//console.log("Moused Out");                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep variable reference to marker which are declared at top of javascript such as `var marker;`

See my [**JS fiddle**: Showing and hiding marker on mouse over and out](http://jsfiddle.net/NUkCs/1/)

**Edit:** I noticed that I demonstrated this using normal map instead of polygon - but same code should work since polygon seems to support same events, see list here: [google maps api polygon events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon)

Well, here is the example when using polygon: **[JS fiddle polygon](http://jsfiddle.net/NUkCs/3/)** , trick is to store marker to actual polygon object so it is easy to access, at least that is what I think :) - also If you want to add several polygons try storing them all inside array instead of some global polygon variable ;) Cheers!

Comment: Thank You. This will help a lot. Now I just need to get all the sections to work.

Comment: I will update my answer in a sec, I will also provide that polygon version, but thnx so far! :)